# Syntax error em calculadora básica Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiquei de programar uma calculadora básica (somar, dividir, multiplicar, dividir absolutamente, achar o resto da divisão e potencia).

O código é esse :

```
operando_1=input()

operando=input()

operando_2=input()

resultado=None

if operando_1.isdigit():
    operando_1=int(operando_1)
    tipo_operando='int'

else:
    operando_1=float(operando_1)
    tipo_operando='float'

if operando_2.isdigit():
    operando_2=int(operando_2)
    tipo_operando='int'
else:
    operando_2=float(operando_2)
    tipo operando='float'

if operando=='+':
    resultado=operando_1+operando_2
elif operando=='-':
    resultado=operando_1-operando_2
elif operando=='*':
    resultado=operando_1*operando_2
elif operando=='//':
    if operando_2==0 or operando_2==0.0:
        print('Falso.')
    else:
        resultado=operando_1//operando_2
elif operando=='%':
    if operando_2==0 or operando_2==0.0:
        print('Falso.')
    else:
        resultado=operando_1%operando_2
elif operando=='/': 
    if operando_2==0 or 2==0.0:
        print('Falso')
    else:
        resultado=operando_1/operando_2
elif operando=='**':
    resultado=operando_1**operando_2

if type(resultado)==float:
    print(format(resultado,'.2f'))
elif type(resultado)==int:
    print(resultado)
```

O error que tem dado é esse `Syntax error: multiple statement found while compiling a single statement`.

Os problemas são:

1 - Não sei se estou executando corretamente o código ou da maneira certa

2 - Tenho feito tudo no notepad, não sei se tem algum programa que facilita a leitura e/ou descoberta de erros.

Comment: Exceto o erro de digitação na linha 22, aqui pareceu rodar normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo pareceu rodar bem excepto um erro de syntax na linha 22. Apenas acho que o programa está um pouco confuso. E respondendo à pergunta 2, para programas simples como este e para uma rápida edição recomendo o sublime text, mais tarde poderia usar uma IDE ou continuar com sublime ou qualquer outro.

Para download do sublime: https://www.sublimetext.com/

Answer (score 0):

1- Na sua linha 22 falta o _ em tipo operando='float'
A execuçao sendo ou nao por editor sera a mesma.

2- A descoberta de erro vai ser dada no terminal de maneira igual